# On iPhones form.submit() javascript does not work again when clicking back to the cached page

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ios-simulator

Test Platform: Xcode iOS Simulator App (iPhone iOS 9.3)

Repro Steps:

- Open a "webview" page with a form on the iOS app
- Open safari JS console
- Hit $("#myForm").submit() in the console
- Form submit happens and user goes to next page
- Hit back (or cancel) button on the app
- User comes back to the cached page from history
- Hit $("#myForm").submit() in the console again
- Nothing happens!

Does iOS restrict submission of form "through javascript" multiple times on a cached page?

This seems to work if I "physically" click on the submit button but doesn't work through javascript.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: What about disabling cache.

Comment: Without page caching it should work since the page is refreshed. But I am facing this issue when we show the cached page from history on the app. This is something that we anyways cannot control since users can decide what settings to have.